# Footer div text wont line up

Tags: html, css

What im trying to do is lining up the 3 divs in the footer. But I cant seem to get them to line up properly. When I try to use float only two of them will line up while the third one will go below them. Anyone know whats going on?

```css
body{
 background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

#pageFooter{
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: red;
 height: 200px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888;
}

#pageFooter p{
 color: white;
 padding-left: 1em;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#leftFooter{
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

#midFooter{
 text-align: center;
 float: center;
 position: relative;
}

#rightFooter{
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Oppgave 1</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/meyersReset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainStyle.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
      <footer id="pageFooter">
     <div id="leftFooter">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
    
     <div id="midFooter">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    
     <div id="rightFooter">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
    </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to add a width for each column?

Comment: `float: center;` ? sadly it does not exists. **Use `float:left;` for all of them.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `display: table` technique suits for your situation:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#pageFooter {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888;
  display: table;/*Add display table*/
  width: 100%;
}
#pageFooter p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#leftFooter {
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;/*add display table-cell*/
  position: relative;
}
#midFooter {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;/*add display table-cell*/
  position: relative;
}
#rightFooter {
  text-align: right;
  display: table-cell;/*add display table-cell*/
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <footer id="pageFooter">
      <div id="leftFooter">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div id="midFooter">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div id="rightFooter">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `float: center` property.

You have to `float` divs `left` and add width to get them aligned properly.

```css
body{
 background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

#pageFooter{
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: red;
 height: 200px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888;
}

#pageFooter p{
 color: white;
 padding-left: 1em;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#leftFooter, #midFooter, #rightFooter{
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Oppgave 1</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/meyersReset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainStyle.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
      <footer id="pageFooter">
     <div id="leftFooter">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
    
     <div id="midFooter">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    
     <div id="rightFooter">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
    </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```